# Android jni and opencv runtime couldn't load libs

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

Recently I'm writing android JNI codes with opencv for picture processing. When I port the C++ code to JNI, there's no error in compiling, but when I run the code on my phone, the program crashes all the time. The logcat shows that

'Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1892]: could not load needed library 'libopencv_java.so' for 'libmixed_sample.so' (load_library[1094] : Library 'libopencv_java.so' not found)'.

The error means that there's no libopencv_java.so library, so I copy the .so to JNI folder and run again and the same runtime error again.

I search for the answer for the problem, and find that 'add

System.loadLibrary("opencv_java")

to java code' may solve the problem. I tried, and the runtime error changed to

'Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_java: find library returned null'.

I'm confused. I searched and tried many methods to solve this problem, but none of them can work.

Anyone know of the fix to this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the lib inside the lib folder so it gets packaged with the app ?

Answer (score 0):

libopencv_java.so library should not be in JNI folder. To be automagically installed from your APK, put it in `libs/armeabi` subdirectory of your Android project. The trick is that if your project has custom JNI code, this directory will be purged during `ndk-build`. Therefore, you should add

```
LOCAL_PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARIES += ocvj

…

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= ocvj
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FOO_PATH)/libopencv_java.so
include $(PREBUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Maybe, you need to add more libraries. Maybe, you use armeabi-v7a instead of armeabi.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I copied libopencv_java.so to libs/armeabi-v7a subdirectory, but it disappeared automatically in one second. How could this be? I also added your code to Android.mk, but it did not work, the runtime error was still 'find library returned null'. Is there other method to solve this problem? Thank you again.

Comment: _"it disappeared automatically in one second"_ - that's exactly what I expected. Regarding `Android.mk` - please publish your file if possible, to put the proposed change in context.

Comment: I just use the opvencv sample Android.mk. I do not know how to add code in comment, so the code is above.

Answer (score 0):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := mixed_sample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni_part.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a shared library of OpenCV

```
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
OPENCV_PATH:=C:\PATH_TO_JNI\OpenCV.mk
$(info $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
include $(OPENCV_PATH)
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```